# Issue with GM for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, node-imagemagick

I'd like to use GM in my nodejs application but it seems not working... I get an error message when I try to get the size of my image...

My code :

```
gm(request.files.file.path)
.size(function (err, size) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

My error message :

```
{[Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn'}
```

My file is well uploaded and when I put `request.files.file.path`, I have a right path of the file.

**EDIT #1:**

```
console.log(request.files.file.path);

// public\uploads\d8fsd5645fsd4fsd4fsd5f4sd65.png
```

**EDIT #2:**

[image]

Comment: can you share the path? and have you tried specifying the full path of your file?

Comment: Yes see edit #1 above :)

Comment: ok, so you're on Windows. Have you tried it with full path to the image, like `C:\nodeapp\public\uploads\d8fsd5645fsd4fsd4fsd5f4sd65.png` ?

Comment: No but I get an error message with that, see edit #2

Comment: node is `javascript` and they take backward slash as escape character, so you have to replace ` \ ` with ` / ` or you can use ` \\ ` for single backslash, so your path would be like `C:\\users\\abc.....`

Comment: No it doesn't work too with '/'... I get the same error message like edit #1...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61668/discussion-between-ravi-and-tonymx227).